# Compare String with curdate() - Mysql

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I plan to make a selection of multiple database tables.

The problem is that I want the current date is equal to current date, only that it is of type `varchar`, I can't make a direct comparison with the `CURDATE ()` ... Is there any way to compare the current date with the String type?

Code:

```
select records.date , records.hour, records.Temp, records.Hum, sensors.idSensor,   sensors.idLocalization
from records, sensors
where records.idSensor=sensors.idSensor
      and records.date = curdade() // Here is where I wanted to make the comparison date    
      order by records.date desc;
```

------------------EDIT (Solved)--------------------------

Thank you all for your help.

I switched CURDATE by curdade.

He made the comparison correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the `curdate()` to a string of the appropriate format.  Something like:

```
select r.date, r.hour, r.Temp, r.Hum, s.idSensor, s.idLocalization
from records r join
     sensors s
     on r.idSensor = s.idSensor
where r.date = date_format(curdate(), '%Y-%m-%d') // Here is where I wanted to make the comparison date    
order by r.date desc;
```

You need to use the appropriate format for your `date` column.  I just used the "right" format, the ISO standard date format that is the best to use when representing a date as a string.  You can read about the formats in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).  And, it is better to turn the current date into the right format than to convert the string to a date.  By putting the function on the "constant" part of the comparison, MySQL can still take advantage of an index on `date`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It may work. But this is a date-to-date data type comparison, not a string-to-string comparison.

```
select STR_TO_DATE(records.date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS date , records.hour, records.Temp, records.Hum, sensors.idSensor,   sensors.idLocalization
     from records, sensors
      where records.idSensor=sensors.idSensor
      and date = curdate() // Here is where I wanted to make the comparison date    
      order by date desc;
```